# C# Format DateTime ddMMMyy

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a way to format DateTime into the following String in C#?:

```
29JUN91
```

I cant find anything online that allows us to write the month in short string form.

Comment: `ToString("dMMMyy");`

Comment: @HelpASisterOut then you need to explain how it didnt work as this is the answer

Comment: *"I cant find anything online [...]"* [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) is the first hit for me when I search for "C# datetime format"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for custom date formating

```
DateTime input = new DateTime(1991, 6, 29); //29JUN91
string result = input.ToString("ddMMMyy").ToUpper();
```

- `dd` for 2 digit day
- `MMM` for abbreviated name of the month
- `yy` for 2 digit year, from 00 to 99

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ToString("ddMMMyy")`

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyy"); // case sensitive
```

use `.ToUpper();` if you want to convert month in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyy").ToUpper();
```